# Elastic Search is mapping date fields wrong (milliseconds instead of seconds)

Tags: elasticsearch, date-formatting

I have mapping defined as follows:

```
PUT test1
{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed":true

  },
  "mappings": {
    "supersonic": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        },
        "other_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, "other_date" is indexed and shown perfectly fine. The problem is, "date" and "timestamp" are treated as milliseconds as well, thus giving me dates in Jan 1970. The dates themselves arrive within a JSON. Am I missing something here?

Edit: I am using 2.1.1. The returned mapping is (after the first events arrive):

```
{
  "test": {
    "mappings": {
      "supersonic": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties": {
          "biomass_cost": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_second"
          },
          "entity_elements": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "entity_type": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "eventId": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "gameId": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "instanceId": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "ipLong": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "ipLongForwarded": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "ipLongPeer": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "networkId": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "platform_id": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "playerId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "production_id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "production_type": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "queue_size": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_second"
          },
          "trevor_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_millis"
          },
          "tsEventAccepted": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "version": {
            "type": "string"
          }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

A JSON would be:

sent:{"ipLongPeer":2130706433,"biomass_cost":110,"networkId":0,"ipLong":3561950994,"gameId":30,"instanceId":0,"tsEventAccepted":1450714430,"trevor_date":1450714430731,"ipLongForwarded":3561950994,"date":1450714430,"production_type":3,"entity_elements":"GA_1_0_0_2_0","version":"0.10.46","timestamp":1450714429,"platform_id":-1,"eventId":945,"playerId":"mzaman","queue_size":1,"entity_type":1100,"production_id":"2015.12.21.17.13.45.8556370.3696111"}

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is correct, and works fine for me with Elasticsearch version 2.2.

A couple suggestions:

- The `date` format `epoch_second` was added in 2.0. Make sure your Elasticsearch version is current.
- Confirm the mapping for your index using the `_mapping` API. For example: `GET test1/_mapping`.
- Double-check the JSON documents being indexed.

**EDIT**

To confirm your dates are being parsed properly, you can run a manual query against your date fields using a `range` query. For example, based on your sample doc (with a date value 1450714430, which translates to 2012-12-21 16:13:50 UTC), try this search:

```
GET /test1/supersonic/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "2015-12-20",
        "lte": "2015-12-22"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The sample doc should be returned by this query, along with any other documents whose `date` falls within that range.

Comment: Good, then that rules out the ES version being the issue. @olkoza, can you provide some sample JSON documents that have been indexed?

Comment: @olkoza, I see the edit. That all looks correct too. So where do you run into the problem? Where do your `timestamp` and `date` fields show up as Jan 1970? Is it when you do a search or aggregation of some kind? This all still works as expected for me.

Comment: When I query the data with Kibana

Comment: @olkoza, see my edited answer. Run a manual `range` query against your data to make sure the documents are returned that way. If they are, then your issue is probably in Kibana somewhere. Is it possible that some of your documents are missing `date` or `timestamp`, in which case they are being treated as Jan 1970?